# how to use popup in django admin to select from another class

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i want to use popup to fill input in django admin i saw it in class Email addresses as the follwing pic
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an attribute `raw_id_fields` that you can use while registering your models in the admin section.
`raw_id_fields = ('author',)`
Its use is that the author field is displayed with a lookup widget that can scale much better than a drop-down select input when you have thousands of users.

[image: example]